# jQuery success POST php not activate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm racking my brain and I can not make it work.

I am using jQuery to call a PHP page:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: postUrl,
      data: formData,
      async : false,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: App.successfulAdd,
      error: App.errorAdd
    });

successfulAdd : function(result) {
    alert("Success!");
},
```

The PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'failed'));
```

Firebug show:

```
{"msg":"failed"}
```

But the successfulAdd function is not called! Any idea why?

---

I have changed to

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: postUrl,
      data: formData,
      async : false,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        alert("Success!");
        },
      error: function (data) {
        alert("Error!");
        }
    });
```

But still Error! is displayed.

**Update**

Finally I found!
Use Notepad++ and was as UTF8 encoding. Changed to UTF8 without BOM and now everything works beautifully.

Comment: Look in your console - what is the status of the request?

Comment: I think you left out some important portion of code. `successfulAdd : ` surely resides in some object, where is that?

Comment: It looks like you're making the AJAX call before you assign `App.successfulAdd`, so it doesn't have a value at that moment. Please show the whole code.

Comment: @tymeJV I think the status is 200. It's right?

Comment: Put `console.log(App.successfulAdd);` before `$.ajax`, I think you'll see I'm right.

Comment: @Barmar I put console.log(App.successfulAdd); before $.ajax and the Firebug show  function(result)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
success: function(result) {
    App.successfulAdd(result);
},
error: function(result) {
    App.errorAdd(result);
}
```

This will evaluate the properties when the response arrives, not when you send the request. I suspect you're sending the request while you're building the `App` object, and these properties haven't been assigned yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the cause of the problem: the version of jQuery.

The versions: 1.11.1, 1.11.0, 1.10.2, 1.10.1, 1.10.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.0 not working.
The version 1.8.3 works.

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted has changed significantly between jQuery versions. It sounds like there's a problem in your code that the old version doesn't detect, but newer versions have added more checking.